# Swift in iOS with AVAudioPlayer: Singleton not working the way I hoped it would

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, avaudioplayer

I am using a standard Master-Detail project, listing songs in the Master and playing them in Detail. Each song has up to four parts playing simultaneously, with independent volume control, so I have four AVAudioPlayer objects in Detail, each with a slider with an IBOutlet and an IBAction to implement the volume control.

The problem is that when you click on a song (in the list on the Master), the previous song doesn't stop.  Both songs play, although the volume controls now only control the most recent song. This can go on for any number of songs.

I want to get rid of the currently playing song when a new song is clicked on.

I thought I might be able to accomplish this by creating the players inside a Singleton, in such a way that there would only ever be four players.  Since, according to the documentation, each player can only play one sound file at a time, I hoped the previous sound file would stop playing when the new one started.  But it's not working. The same behavior described above is still happening: multiple songs can play simultaneously, with the volume controls only controlling the most recent song.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for the Singleton:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class FourPlayers {
       static let audioPlayers = [one, two, three, four]

        static let one = AVAudioPlayer()
        static let two = AVAudioPlayer()
        static let three = AVAudioPlayer()
        static let four = AVAudioPlayer()

        private init() {} //This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.
}
```

(Initially, I had just made `audioPlayers` static, but when that didn't work, I decided to make each individual player static as well.)

Then, in the DetailViewController:

```
var audioPlayers = FourPlayers.audioPlayers
```

Here's code for one of the four volume controls:

```
@IBOutlet weak var vol1: UISlider!

@IBAction func volAdjust1(sender: AnyObject) {
    audioPlayers[0].volume = vol1.value
}
```

Playing a song looks like this (the audioFiles array is populated when the song info is passed in from the Master):

```
var audioFiles = []

func  playAudioFiles() {
    var i = 0
    for _ in audioFiles {
        audioPlayers[i].play()
        i+=1
    }
}
```

This is the code telling the players which file to play:

```
func prepareAudioFiles () {
    var i = 0;
    for audioFile in audioFiles {
        let s = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(audioFile as? String, ofType: "mp3")!)
        do {
            audioPlayers[i] = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:s)
        } catch {
            print("Error getting the audio file")
        }
        audioPlayers[i].prepareToPlay()
        self.audioPlayers[i].delegate = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the the volume control is only adjusting the first player (index 0)

```
@IBAction func volAdjust1(sender: AnyObject) {
    audioPlayers[0].volume = vol1.value
}
```

maybe you could add a variable to keep track of the currently playing index

```
var currentlyPlayingIndex = 0
@IBAction func volAdjust1(sender: AnyObject) {
    audioPlayers[currentlyPlayingIndex].volume = vol1.value
}
```

And update it when needed

When you play the audio you could use the same variable

```
func  playAudioFiles() {
    var i = 0
    for _ in audioFiles {

        if i == currentlyPlayingIndex {
            audioPlayers[i].play()
        } else {
            audioPlayers[i].stop()
        }
        i+=1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I only showed code for one of the four volume controls.  But there are three others just like it.  And all four players are playing simultaneously.  Here's the problem: Say the first song has three simultaneous tracks and the second one has four. When I click the first  song, the three tracks play.  That's fine.  When I click the second one, those four start, but the other three don't stop.  So I've got seven tracks playing simultaneously, three from the first song and four from the second song.  I want the three to terminate when the four start. Hope this is clear!

Comment: I think i follow, when are you calling stop() or pause() ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line:

```
var audioPlayers = FourPlayers.audioPlayers
```

You are actually creating a new copy of the FourPlayers.audioPlayers array into the audioPlayers variable. So you are not reusing the AVAudioPlayers but creating independent ones for each song.

See the "Assignment and Copy Behavior for Strings, Arrays, and Dictionaries" section in the [Swift Programming Documentation, Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_145)

You could use the static variable directly in your code instead of making a copy, for example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var vol1: UISlider!

@IBAction func volAdjust1(sender: AnyObject) {
    FourPlayers.audioPlayers[0].volume = vol1.value
}
```

and:

```
var audioFiles = []

func  playAudioFiles() {
    var i = 0
    for _ in audioFiles {
        FourPlayers.audioPlayers[i].play()
        i+=1
    }
}
```

and update the rest of your code accordingly.